# C# Async Socket works well in local, but leaks in remote

Tags: c#, sockets, memory, asynchronous, memory-leaks

I have a client application that sends datas (images, audio) to a server application through TCP and UDP using async sockets.

The client can send its datas to the server, and everything works fine ... when the client and the server are on the same machine.

If not, applications are still working, but there are some memory leaks, causing the memory usage grows very quickly as you can see below.

http://imgur.com/emVl0Fs

The profiler shows me an large increasing number of Byte[], but I can't figure out why my code works well in local and leaks in remote ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that is reported to leak.

Comment: You've not provided much information but I highly suspect that the "memory leak" will have manifested in the send callback. When the client and server are on the same machine they usually transmit data quick enough that a single send does correspond to a single receive and you will not need to read any more data from the TCP buffer.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [Question Check list](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Comment: JoachimIsaksson : This is a huge project and it will be hard to provide you the code.

@ByteBlast : That's possible. Have you any idea of how can I fix this issue ?